# Visible binding with function having a parameter

Tags: knockout.js

I am getting the following error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to parse binding attribute.
>   Message: TypeError: Object expected; Attribute value: visible:
>   `IsVisible('Area')`

I am trying to hide / show my html elements based on some evaluation. This is my code:

```
 var viewModel = {
            propertyTypeList: ko.observableArray([]),
            selectedPropertyType: ko.observable(""),
            visibleFeatures: ko.observableArray([]),
            IsVisible : function(featureName){some logic here}
        };
```

And this is the view:

```html
<div class="editor-field">
    <select data-bind="options: propertyTypeList, 
                       optionsText: 'PropertyTypeName', 
                       value: selectedPropertyType, 
                       optionsCaption: 'select property type...'">
    </select>
</div>

<div class="editor-label" data-bind="visible: IsVisible('Area')">
    Area
</div>
<div class="editor-label" data-bind="visible: IsVisible('Bedroom')">
  Bedroom
</div>
```

The function `IsVisible` will do some evaluation based on the `selectedPropertyType` and the feature name and will return true or false.

Comment: It should work; A similar example works for me > http://jsfiddle.net/EhEsd/ . Does the select data-binding works?

Comment: text and value binding working for me and visible binding works if there is a boolean property in the view model. Not working when it is a function

Comment: can you show what you are doing inside the IsVisible function? It should be returning a true/false. Your above code looks all set, there is something else which is causing the bug.

Comment: You are right. I think the return type of IsVisible was incorrect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706281/knockoutjs-can-we-create-a-dependentobservable-function-with-a-parameter

Comment: Pinakin Shah, I assume you have solved the problem already. Could you please post you solution and mark it as an accepted answer to help the community?

Comment: sure. Missed this one. will update shortly

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the method in following way

```
<div class="editor-label" data-bind="visible: $root.IsVisible('Area')">
```

or

```
<div class="editor-label" data-bind="visible: viewModel.IsVisible('Area')">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the visibility of those divs to change dynamically (which it seems that you might), you will want to to make isVisible a [computedObservable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). That will make sure that the isVisible logic gets re-run when observables (that it depends on) change.

it could return a string which you could bind you visibility to (data-bind="visible: isVisible() === 'Area'"), or you could create a different computed for each div if they are unrelated. (isAreaVisilbe, isBedroomVisible, ...)  Your viewModel essentially turns into something like this:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.propertyTypeList = ko.observableArray(['Area', 'Bedroom', 'Other']);
    self.selectedPropertyType = ko.observable("");
    self.visibleFeatures = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.visibleDiv = ko.computed(function () {
        //Your logic here
        return self.selectedPropertyType();
    });
```

I made a basic working example of what I think you are trying to make here http://jsfiddle.net/ZqWDS/5/
Had to change your viewModel to be a function so that the isVisible property can reference other properties.  ([How to reference properties of current object in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034476/how-to-reference-properties-of-current-object-in-js)).  And you can read the section titled 'A popular convention that simplifies things' on the knockout computedObservables page for more details about why I structured the viewModel constructor that way.

I'm not sure what's causing your error at the top of the question.  I pasted your code into a jsFiddle and it essentially worked (with a few minor syntax edits) http://jsfiddle.net/GBkdK/

If you are still having issues and want to provide some more context, I'm happy to help.

**EDIT**
Sorry, I think I was wrong about isVisible needing to be a computed.  It appears that it could just be a function like you originally had it. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZqWDS/6/

[knockoutjs: can we create a dependentObservable function with a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706281/knockoutjs-can-we-create-a-dependentobservable-function-with-a-parameter?lq=1)

Comment: But, can you also send a parameter to that computed observable to get different results?