# Is it possible to have a computed observable with parameters in Knockout

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [knockoutjs: can we create a dependentObservable function with a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706281/knockoutjs-can-we-create-a-dependentobservable-function-with-a-parameter)

In my viewmodel, I have a function that returns the sum of items based on the type of item:

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;

    this.Results = ko.observableArray(data);

    this.totalPerType = function(type) {
        var total = 0;
        for (var index in self.Results()) {
            if (self.Results()[index].Type == type)
                total += self.Results()[index].Quantity;
        }

        return total;
    };
};
```

When the user edits one of the items, the total isn't updated automatically, because it isn't a computed observable. Is it possible to change the function *totalPerType* into a computed observable, without having to put the type parameter into the viewmodel (keeping it as a parameter)?

I created a Fiddle to make it easier to try some things: http://jsfiddle.net/7PK9r/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this answers your question:

[knockoutjs: can we create a dependentObservable function with a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706281/knockoutjs-can-we-create-a-dependentobservable-function-with-a-parameter)

(Note: `dependentObservable` is what computed observables used to be called prior to v2.0 of knockout.js)

Comment: I had to change the example a bit to make it work, but thanks! You can find the working example here: [http://jsfiddle.net/2pB9Y/41/](http://jsfiddle.net/2pB9Y/41/)