# Reusable Computed Fields in Knockout

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, computed-observable

I have a Knockout Viewmodel that uses the mapping plugin. After mapping the JSON object, I create some computed values, like so:

```
/* viewmodel setup and mapping */

myViewModel
    .formattedGiftAmount = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return parseInt(this.giftAmount(), 10).formatMoney();                        
        }
        , write: function (value) {                        
            this.giftAmount(value.unformatMoney());
        }
        , owner: this        
    })
    .formattedGoal = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            return parseInt(this.goalAmount(), 10).formatMoney();                        
        }
        , write: function (value) {                        
            this.goalAmount(value.unformatMoney());
        }
        , owner: this        
});
```

Don't worry so much about what the code does, I'm more concerned with the pattern. As you can see, the two properties `formattedGiftAmount()` and `formattedGoal()` have nearly identical objects that define them. The only difference is what properties they modify. I'm potentially going to have many more instances like this, so I was wondering if there was any way to make this more reusable. I can imagine doing something like `this[prop]()`, but I can't quite figure out how to inject that into the object and get it to work.

PS: I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706281/knockoutjs-can-we-create-a-dependentobservable-function-with-a-parameter) but it still doesn't quite do what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a function to your view model that creates a formatted property based on an unformatted property:

```
myViewModel.addFormattedProperty = function(formattedName, unformattedName) {
    this[formattedName] = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return parseInt(this[unformattedName](), 10).formatMoney();                        
        },
        write: function(value) {
            this[unformattedName](value.unformatMoney());

        },
        owner: this
    });
};
```

Then you could call it for your properties:

```
myViewModel.addFormattedProperty('formattedGiftAmount', 'giftAmount');
myViewModel.addFormattedProperty('formattedGoalAmount', 'goalAmount');
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also [modify fn](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html) to add a function to your ko.observable to create it, this will allow you to add the properties in your constructor in a descriptive way ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgoemat/nwJvy/)):

```
ko.observable.fn.formatAsMoney = function() {
    var base = this;
    return ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return formatMoney(parseFloat(base()));
        },
        write: function(newValue) {
            base(unformatMoney(newValue));
        }
    });
};

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.number = ko.observable(10.5);
    self.money = self.number.formatAsMoney();
};
```