# Using Knockout to Populate Bootstrap Rows and Spans

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

Well essentially I'm trying to populate a Bootstrap template via Knockout and a JSON object.

#### Bootstrap scaffolding:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>App Title</h1>
        <p>App Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>App Title</h1>
        <p>App Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>App Title</h1>
        <p>App Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>App Title</h1>
        <p>App Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>App Title</h1>
        <p>App Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <h1>App Title</h1>
        <p>App Description</p>
    </div>
</div>
...
```

#### Here is the Knockout code we're using:

```
var viewModel;

$.get('AppData.json', function (data) {
    jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
    viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(jsonData);
    var apps = viewModel.Apps();
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

The problem is that I cannot get Knockout to inject the `</div><div class="row-fluid">` required after running a knockout conditional of index modulo 3... I'm assuming because those `<div>` tags are dangling / not closed.

**In short, how do I get `viewModel.Apps();`'s array of objects to fit within the above Bootstrap scaffolding?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make a computed observable which slices `apps` observable/observable array into arrays of three elements, and then bind some root element to it with `foreach` binding. Something like this.

Observable:

```
viewModel.appRows = ko.computed(function() {
    var apps = this.Apps();
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < apps.length; i += 3) {
        var row = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
            if (apps[i + j]) {
                row.push(apps[i + j]);
            }
        }
        result.push(row);
    }
    return result;
}, viewModel);
```

Markup:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="foreach: appRows">
    <div class="row-fluid" data-bind="foreach: $data">
        <div class="span4">
            <h1 data-bind="text: title"></h1>
            <p data-bind="text: description"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had to put .span4 inside a new <!-- ko foreach: $data --> to make it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I had to solve a very similar problem myself: rendering bootstrap grids with an observable array but with bootstrap v3 and ko v3.0. I'll leave my solution here for future reference.

I'm using a plain function instead of a computed one, since binding are implemented using them by default (see RP Niemeyer answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6712389/323751)

In my View Model:

```
this.partitioned = function (observableArray, count) {
    var rows, partIdx, i, j, arr;

    arr = observableArray();

    rows = [];
    for (i = 0, partIdx = 0; i < arr.length; i += count, partIdx += 1) {
        rows[partIdx] = [];
        for (j = 0; j < count; j += 1) {
            if (i + j >= arr.length) {
                break;
            }
            rows[partIdx].push(arr[i + j]);
        }
    }
    return rows;
};
```

Template:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: partitioned(userProjects, 3)">
  <div class="row"
       data-bind="template: { name: 'projectCell', foreach: $data }"></div>
</div>

<script id="projectCell" type="text/html">
  <div class="col-md-4" data-bind="text: name"></div>
</script>
```

Hope somebody find this useful.

Comment: For anyone still looking: I had a problem where my books (col-md-3) were not rapping properly because of the size of the images on an uncounted number of books (turns out they were 29 and would not rap in columns of 4) I believe this is relevant because this solution worked but I never saw the simple clearfix provided.... I used the following solution, as well as, this one to render: stackoverflow.com/a/25682250/3997521. I would also like to add that CSS for some reason STILL does count elements even if they are hidden from the view... See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32380418/3997521 for more.

Answer (score 1):

I´m using bootstrap3 and wanted to have x objects per row, where x is depending on the window size e.g on the col class.

e.g i have elements with class :

```
col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4
```

so

if xs then a row has 3 items

if lg then a row has 6 items ...

I extended the answer of rkhayrov to put it to work

```
/* determine the current bootstrap environment */
function findBootstrapEnvironment() {
    var envs = ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg'];

    $el = $('<div>');
    $el.appendTo($('body'));

    for (var i = envs.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var env = envs[i];

        $el.addClass('hidden-'+env);
        if ($el.is(':hidden')) {
            $el.remove();
            return env
        }
    };
}


/* determine How many objs per row */
function determineObjectsPerRow(){
    switch(findBootstrapEnvironment()) {
        case 'xs':
            return 3;
            break;
        case 'sm':
            return 4;
            break;
        case 'md':
            return 6;
            break;
        case 'lg':
            return 6;
            break;
    }
}


        var objsPerRow= determineObjectsPerRow();

        for (var i = 0; i < apps.length; i += objsPerRow) {
            var row = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < objsPerRow; ++j) {
                if (apps[i + j]) {
                    row.push(apps[i + j]);
                }
            }
            result.push(row);
        }
```

i added a dependency to width and height, which are observables
So the functions will be recomputed if window is resized

```
var base = {
    AppModel:function (data) {
        var self = this;
        self.data = ko.observable({
            documents:ko.observableArray([]),
            width:ko.observable($(window).width()),
            height:ko.observable($(window).height())
        });

        /* calculate rows based on bootstrap environment */
        self.appRows = ko.computed(function() {
            self.data().height();
            self.data().width();
            var apps = self.data().documents();
            var result = [];
            var objsPerRow= determineObjectsPerRow();

            for (var i = 0; i < apps.length; i += objsPerRow) {
                var row = [];
                for (var j = 0; j < objsPerRow; ++j) {
                    if (apps[i + j]) {
                        row.push(apps[i + j]);
                    }
                }
                result.push(row);
            }
            return result;
        }, self); 

    },
};
```

and the resize handler

```
$(window).resize(function(event) {
    vm.data().height($(window).height());
    vm.data().width($(window).width());
});
```

it just works like a Charme, the rows are generated nicely for each device-width

i leave it here if anyone needs to achieve the same