# Bootstrap 3 Push whole row when column height increases

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 for grid layout.

[image]

Problem arises when resizing
[image]

I have used following classes in a column:

```
col-sm-4 col-ms-6 col-xs-12 col-md-3
```

The expected behaviour is that the whole row should be pushed when column height increases.

I searched for similar issue here and found this but it didn't help
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19946033/bootstrap-row-text-pushing-columns-down)

Comment: If you're able to use v4.x of Bootstrap its flexbox Grid approach will alleviate this issue without the need for additional code. Otherwise I recommend following the advice of Nadeem Gorsi whose answer is *perfect* for Bootstrap 3.

Comment: @RobertC Right now I'm not planning for the upgrade to v4.x. However, thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: it seems `col-ms-6` is not valid class of bootstrap 3. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-options

Comment: @Banzay I have used a custom class for mid small range

Answer (score 1):

Create one `<div class="row"></div>` for every four columns or products/items.

Or User This after every 4 items (divs you are using for your products)

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: If I programmed to add clearfix after every fourth element, when I resize to smaller devices which renders 3 columns then it clears the float after the fourth item. So it doesn't work this way either. changing after how many numbers to add clearfix when resizing I think would be inefficient.

Comment: you can remove clearfix on smaller devices using javascript/jQuery.

Comment: I was searching for only CSS hack.i have not used jquery in the project and I am also not using javascript for handling the responsiveness of the site. The above answer works well when there are four columns so I upvoted the answer. I appreciate your answer, unfortunately, it doesn't provide me the solution.

Comment: Then create your custom clearfix like myClearfix to work on only your desired media query.

Comment: I think this solution is good enough but is too crude, though it has to be extended with `visible-**-*` class : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities-classes since you want to use pure bootstrap 3