# How to reference properties of current object in JS

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

I have some simple objects in JS like this example:

```
var object = {
 firstname : 'john',
 lastname : 'paul',
 wholename : firstname + lastname
}
```

Well this simple thing doesn't work; john and paul are undefined in wholename, so I tried to use the 'this' operator which works ONLY if I do a function `(getWholeName(){return this.firstname+this.lastname} )`.
But if I want to use a variable and not a function, how can I do? I also tried `object.firstname + object.lastname` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to reference the object, but you can add the properties dynamically:

```
var object = { 
    firstname : 'john', 
    lastname : 'paul'
};

object.wholename = object.firstname + object.lastname;
```

**EDIT:**

And why not wrap it in a function?

```
var makePerson = function (firstname, lastname) {
    return {
        firstname: firstname,
        lastname: lastname,
        wholename: firstname + lastname  // refers to the parameters
    };
};

var object = makePerson('john', 'paul');
```

Comment: Ok thank you. The why I am doing this is that I am trying to have a well organized code in a huge web app I am building ; and so I decided to regroup similar functions and variables in objects like this. Is this the right way of doing it ? I know about TypeScript and Modules but do I need to use TS to achieve something as simple as groups of functions/variables ?

Comment: @user1397271 you can do this in plain JS: try introducing namespaces (like var MYAPP = { }; MYAPP.data = ...) and try breaking down big functions into smaller ones. Consider using the module pattern: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth

Comment: when you say namespaces like var MYAPP = {}, it means it is the same as my example with var object = {}, so will I run into the problem I was asking about ?

Comment: @user1397271 yes, it will if you need to reference the thing that you're defining at the same time. But libraries can help with that, i.e. https://github.com/fabiooshiro/namespace-js or http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/

Answer (score 3):

In Javascript, every function is an object. You should declare your Object's constructor as a function like this:

```
function person(firstname,lastname)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;

this.wholeName=wholeName;

 //this will work but is not recommended.
 function wholeName()
 {
 return this.firstname+this.lastname;
 }
}
```

you can add extra methods to your object by prototyping it aswell , which is the recommended way of doing things. More info here:

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/proto.shtml

Comment: if everything is a function...what's this => `var obj={1:1,2:2}`?

Comment: You are right, but every function is an object though. That's what i meant. I stand corrected :)

Comment: Did you just rip this off of w3schools or some other website?